# Failure to load the native-hadoop library

Tags: java, hadoop

Without -Djava.library.path=/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/ as an argument to running Java, I get the following error,

```
2013-11-13 15:23:29,414 WARN    pool-3-thread-3 org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-11-13 15:23:29,414 INFO    pool-3-thread-3 org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback        Falling back to shell based
```

What does this mean?  Is it slower to use shell based?  Should I fix this? Should I care about this warning?

FYI this error (or an UnspecifiedLinkError) can be fixed by either of the following,

- See this answer for details setting the java.library.path - [rhive.connect() issues with MapR distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058295/rhive-connect-issues-with-mapr-distribution)
- To the file hadoop-env.sh add the following line

  export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `WARN` message that you get, I assume you already figured it out, but this just means that you are not using the native libraries for Hadoop which could be slower or just not working properly for gzip.

But for your second message from `JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback` it's a bit more complex. If you look at the source you'll see something like this:

```
if (NativeCodeLoader.isNativeCodeLoaded()) {
    this.impl = new JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping();
} else {
    LOG.info("Falling back to shell based");
    this.impl = new ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping();
}
```

The only difference between `ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping` and `JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping` is that `ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping` will just do a `bash -c groups` via a `ProcessBuilder` to figure out which groups a user belongs to, while `JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping` will use JNI to communicate with the libC to get the list of groups.

I haven't run any benchmark, but I don't think there is too much overhead with `ProcessBuilder` compared to the libC implementation since it's just to get the groups so the impact is minimal. That being said, since it looks like you already figured it out, it definitely doesn't hurt using the native libraries for performance improvements in other areas of Hadoop.